# loses focus on input field in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

[image: Grid]

that `focus on the last input field automatically` .. so how can I lose that focus please :)

if you need any piece of code .. let me know thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove it from css.

```
*:focus{
    outline: none;
}
```

This will remove the outline focus for every element, if you want to only remove it for a specific element target it like this:

```
element:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: You can't use pseudoclasses inline, so you better create a css file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use blur() to remove focus.

```
 $('form input[name=email]').blur();
```